# symplectic maps and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

Suppose $J$ is standard symplectic matrix =$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_d\\
-I_d & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Now $\theta$ be any invertible $2d \times 2d$ skew symmetric matrix. Then there exists an invertible $2d \times 2d$  matrix $T_\theta$ such that $T_\theta^tJT_\theta = \theta$. Is the map $\theta \rightarrow T_\theta$ continuous in Euclidean norm?

Comment: Try to prove first that $T_θ$ is unique, i.e., your map is actually a function.

Comment: is unique modulo symplectic matrices. On the other hand can you make continuous choice of $T_\theta$'s

Comment: So you see that it is not as simple as euclidean norms,you have to define the distance of equivalence classes.